# What is the correct syntax for absolute paths in Vite for ReactJS components and pages?

Tags: reactjs, path, vite, absolute-path

I need help with absolute path in Vite(React) relative src. I want to use next path for example: 'components/Main/Main' or if this is a pages folder same thing 'pages/Home/Home'

I tried to many different configurations nothing work to me all starts with exmaple:

```
import { Header } from 'src/components/Header/Header'
```

but I want without src/

Answer (score 0):

To import components or pages without using the src/ prefix in Vite (React), you can configure the module resolution in your Vite project. By default, Vite includes the src/ prefix in the module resolution to provide better control over file inclusion.

To achieve the desired behavior, you need to update the resolve.alias configuration in your vite.config.js file. Here's an example configuration that allows importing components and pages without the src/ prefix:

```
    // vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh';
import path from 'path';

// Resolve aliases
const aliases = {
  '/@/': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') // Replace 'src' with your actual source directory
};

// Vite configuration
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [reactRefresh()],
  resolve: {
    alias: aliases
  }
});
```

With the above configuration, you can import components or pages using the next path format:

```
import { Header } from '@/components/Header/Header'; // Component import
import Home from '@/pages/Home/Home'; // Page import
```

Make sure to replace 'src' in the aliases object with the actual name of your source directory if it's different.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that maybe somebody know a decision when you don`t need to use @ and if its not hard for you for components. If I for example in folder Components try to import any file from the same folder the path will start from '/components'. How to avoid this and ,ake it similar to 'src' ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to prefix `@` to your import paths (as in another answer), you can specify the individual directories to resolve in the vite config:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      components: '/src/components',
      utils: '/src/utils',
      // ...etc.
    }
  }
});
```